# 404 - Other permalink after transfer from localhost(apache) to nginx server

Tags: wordpress, nginx, serve

I've transferred Wordpress site from localhost(apache) to Live server(nginx)
only default link is working and also follow General WordPress rules in codex but
I couldn't find the file path /etc/nginx/global/ or /etc/nginx/conf/global

When I search .conf file it only shows this files:

```
/home/wwwroot/my-domain/etc/nginx-host-subdomain-template.conf
/home/wwwroot/my-domain/etc/nginx-host-template.conf
/home/wwwroot/my-domain/etc/php5.2-fpm-template.conf
/home/wwwroot/my-domain/etc/php-fpm-template.conf
/home/wwwroot/my-domain/etc/main.conf
/home/wwwroot/my-domain/php-fpm/go123.conf
/home/wwwroot/my-domain/vhost/go123.conf
/home/wwwroot/my-domain/rewrite/amh.conf
```

Don't know what file to edit to insert the code in codex. My first time to use nginx

Comment: When transferring from local to live server you need to replace local links with live ones in your database. Use [search and replace tool](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) and then after you've done that, flush your permalinks.

Comment: Yes, all links are working when the Permalinks was set to Default, but when I change to other it's 404

Comment: how do you manage the server? which host do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After those trial and error finally make it works. The main problem is that `mod_rewrite` wasn't enable so I figured it out the file was located here `/home/wwwroot/my-domain/rewrite/amh.conf` and made a rewrite rule for nginx server.
Here is the code:

```
location / {
        index index.php index.html;
        if (!-e $request_filename)
        {
                rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php last;
        }
}
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I assume your nginx `html` directory location is `/usr/share/nginx/html` and your nginx `default.conf` location is `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`

Ok open your nginx default.conf ( `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` ) file on an editor. and replace the file with the following server block content

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  your-domain.com www.your-domain.com;

    client_max_body_size 128m;
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html/your-wp-root-dir;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;
    }
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Update `your-domain` with your domain name and `your-wp-root-dir` with your wp root directory name.

and then restart your nginx server using `sudo service nginx restart` or `sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart`

Comment: can you take a look at this on what location here is `default.conf` is located http://imgur.com/0UPzwSqthe highlighted one is the current websites.

Comment: It looks like managed hosting environment, do you have VPS or Shared hosting.?

Comment: that's the access they gave me. It's my first time to use nginx server. Where do you think the `.conf` file is located? I badly need your help. Thanks

Comment: It should be `/home/wwwroot/my-domain/etc/nginx-host-template.conf` that one, just rename `nginx-host-template.conf` to `default.conf` and place the above server block in it. the you should probably reload nginx config ( there should be some option for that in your hosting control panel )

Comment: This should give you more insights : http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Nginx#Local_configuration_files

Comment: Still giving me 404 I follow your solutions, after I make a changes the url automatically update itself to postname and even I change it to wp-admin it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi I made a bounty for this hope you can help me. thanks

Comment: @winresh24 Which hosting provider you are using.?